# How to store encrypted data

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

I have a virtual server that connects to a database. So in my code I store my database credentials. If one day someone will have an access to my server, he will know my password.

Let's imagine I encrypted my password with [Google KMS](https://cloud.google.com/kms/) (or using any other service/way). Now a hacker can't use directly the password. But my code can't too. So it has to call Google KMS API to decrypt it.

So if a hacker will have an access to my hard drive he can't use my password. But if he will have an entire access to my server (stolen server's credentials), he can execute commands from the server and he can also call Google KMS and decrypt the password.

What are the best practices to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the OS.  In Windows, each process runs in a given security context (i.e.: domain\username).  Each of these accounts has a username and password.  You want to protect your keys by protecting the account password.  For Windows Services, where there's no user to prompt for a password, consider DPAPI.